# Error join de dos tablas. Al hacer un group by y ordenar order by por fecha timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito saber porque me responde como necesito una consulta, tengo una tabla de datos médicos y otra de pacientes donde coinciden dos strings llamados id no están referenciados ni nada.

mi tabla de medicals.

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| id                                   | control | date                | timestamp     |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 2       | 2017-02-21 18:17:22 | 1487719042879 |
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 1       | 2017-02-21 18:16:13 | 1487718961328 |
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 0       | 2017-02-20 13:24:44 | 1487615084580 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
```

mi tabla patients.

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| _id                      | id                                   | nombres       | numeroDocumento |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 5808fb0331a4dd0917e0abf1 | 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | jose geronimo | 17322147        |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

cuando defino un select

```
SELECT 
   id, control, date, timestamp
FROM
    medicals
WHERE
    id = '64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242'
 Group BY id
 ORDER BY date DESC;
```

tengo esto como resultado

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| id                                   | control | date                | timestamp     |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 1       | 2017-02-21 18:16:13 | 1487718961328 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
```

pero en realidad necesito es el control (2)

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| id                                   | control | date                | timestamp     |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 2       | 2017-02-21 18:17:22 | 1487719042879 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
```

porque estoy agrupando y ordenando. pero lo necesito en un join poco mas complicado 
lo intente colocar.

```
SELECT 
   id, control, date, timestamp
FROM
    medicals
WHERE
    id = '64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242'
 order by date desc limit 1;
```

este es el resultado.

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| id                                   | control | date                | timestamp     |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 2       | 2017-02-21 18:17:22 | 1487719042879 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+
```

pero al tener esto inmerso en un join. solo me sigue trayendo para ese id el control 1.

```
SELECT 
    numeroDocumento, nombres, control, medicals.id
FROM
    patients
       JOIN
    medicals ON medicals.id = patients.id
WHERE
    numeroDocumento = '17322147'
GROUP BY medicals.id
ORDER BY medicals.date DESC;
```

tengo como resultado esto..

```
+-----------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| numeroDocumento | nombres       | control | id                                   |
+-----------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 17322147        | jose geronimo | 1       | 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 |
+-----------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

no se que hacer alguna ayuda gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si necesitas sólo el control 2 lo obtienes agregando un `AND` al `WHERE`, algo como `WHERE
    id = '64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242' AND control=2`...

Comment: Me da la impresión que te hace falta considerar una tabla más; en la cual esta incluido el "_id", "id", y "control".

Comment: Y quizá @RobertoLeónOramas tenga razón de que quizá sería mejor una tercera tabla asociativa, ya que en tu tabla `medicals` aparecen varias filas con el mismo id... pero eso dependerá de otras posibles relaciones de tu tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: si el problema es que debe ser dinamico trayendo siempre el ultimo control y la fecha debe ser la mas reciente y el control debe ser el mayor.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo usando tres tablas. Como podrás ver la consulta hace el filtro por control=2 que es lo que decías que te interesaba.

Si por algún motivo la propuesta de usar una tercera tabla no te interesa, puedes adaptar la **Query 1** indicada más abajo en tu diseño actual y debería funcionar.

En caso de usar una tercera tabla yo haría las relaciones a través de un campo id del tipo autonumérico en vez de varchar, pero eso es opcional.

*Notas:*

Creo que es mejor una tercera tabla porque en tus datos actuales tienen columnas que se repiten en ambas tablas.

He puesto la columna `control` en la tercera tabla como una intuición. Al no conocer el diseño completo de la base de datos, esta columna podría estar, como originalmente, en la tabla `medicals`. Si es así, la **Query 1** funcionará si indicas que dicha columna se encuentra en `medicals` y no en la tabla asociativa como he puesto.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8210b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE medicals
    (`medical_id` varchar (50))
;

INSERT INTO medicals
    (`medical_id`)
VALUES
    ('64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242')
;

CREATE TABLE patients
    (`patient_id` varchar(50), `patient_nom` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO patients
    (`patient_id`, `patient_nom`)
VALUES
    ('5808fb0331a4dd0917e0abf1', 'José Gerónimo')
;


CREATE TABLE patients_medical
    (`medical_id` varchar(50), `patient_id` varchar(50), `control` int)
;

INSERT INTO patients_medical
    (`medical_id`, `patient_id`, `control`)
VALUES
    ('64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242', '5808fb0331a4dd0917e0abf1', 1),
    ('64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242', '5808fb0331a4dd0917e0abf1', 2),
    ('64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242', '5808fb0331a4dd0917e0abf1', 3)

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  m.medical_id, p.patient_id, p.patient_nom, pm.control
FROM
  patients_medical pm
INNER JOIN patients p ON pm.patient_id=p.patient_id
INNER JOIN medicals m ON pm.medical_id=m.medical_id
WHERE pm.control=2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8210b/1/0)**:

```
|                           medical_id |               patient_id |   patient_nom | control |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------------|---------------|---------|
| 64f5fac0-96e8-11e6-938b-25cb5cd69242 | 5808fb0331a4dd0917e0abf1 | José Gerónimo |       2 |
```

Comment: si el problema es que siempre debo traer el ultimo control sin definir estático el control.

Comment: @josegeronimo Eso es lo de menos. Cambiando el `WHERE`
... por esto:  `ORDER BY tabla.columnafecha DESC LIMIT 1 ` obtendrías el último control, ya que le dirías a la consulta que te obtenga únicamente el último registro (LIMIT 1) tomando la fecha más reciente (ORDER BY tabla.columnafecha). Creo que es una solución más sencilla y clara que lo planteas en tu auto-respuesta. Editaré el ejemplo cuando funcione sqlfiddle, pues está fuera de servicio ahora. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El modificador [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) siempre devuelve *el primer registro y el resto es descartado*; esto no se puede evitar.

### Solución:

Ya que no se necesita realizar una operación sobre un *"grupo de registros" (`SUM(), COUNT(), etc.`)*, entonces, podemos sacar el modificador `GROUP BY` y en su lugar utilizar `ORDER BY date DESC` para ordenar los registros por su `date` y `LIMIT 1` para limitar a `un solo registros`

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT P.id, P.numeroDocumento, P.nombres, M.control
FROM patients AS P
INNER JOIN medicals AS M
  ON M.id = M.id
WHERE P.numeroDocumento = '17322147'
ORDER BY M.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/DOBW99400)</kbd>

Comment: el problema es cuando quito el where. esto debe quedar sin el documento porque siempre debo traer es a todos. los pacientes que tengan el ultimo control es decir el control más reciente que tengan en medicals.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos encontré una respuesta aplicando teoria de conjuntos hice una consulta que agrupe lo que necesito esa es mi tabla pivot y luego en dos join saco los datos medicos y de paciente.

```
 SELECT medicals.*, patients.*
    FROM (
        SELECT p._id AS p_id, (
            SELECT
                 medicals._id
            FROM patients
                INNER JOIN
                    medicals ON medicals.id = patients.id
            WHERE
                numeroDocumento = p.numeroDocumento
            GROUP BY control
            ORDER BY medicals.date DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS medical_id
        FROM patients AS p
    ) AS pivot
     INNer JOIN patients ON pivot.p_id = patients._id
     INNer JOIN medicals ON pivot.medical_id = medicals._id
```